# Cual es la mejor forma de definir una propiedad de navegacion o relación en CodeFirst

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Amigos lo que pasa es que me inquieta algo, ya que he venido usando las relaciones de esta manera

```
public virtual List<Property> Properties { get; set; }
```

Pero he visto que hay otras formas de hacerlo como:

```
public virtual ICollection<Cliente> Cliente { get; set; }

public virtual ObservableColletion<Persona> Persona { get; set;}
```

cual es la mejor Forma de hacerlo a cuanto a mejores practicas? y que ventajas o desventajas se tiene al usarlo de diferente forma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Un poco de introducción y detalles

La parte de `virtual` es para permitir la carga diferida (**Lazy Loading** en inglés). Puedes referirte al artículo [**Entity Framework Loading Related Entities**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) para saber más al respecto.

Para que la carga diferida trabaje a como se debe, Entity Framework debe poder generar proxys para cada una de las clases POCO utilizadas en el modelo. Cada clase POCO debe cumplir con requerimientos específicos para permitir la generación de proxys.

También está el caso del rastreo de cambios (**Change Tracking** en inglés). Esto permite que los cambios realizados en las propiedades de navegación se apliquen automáticamente, sin necesidad de llamar a métodos como `Attach`, `Entry`, etc. Al igual que en la carga diferida, el rastreo de cambios depende de proxys, y cada clase POCO debe cumplir con requerimientos específicos para permitirlo.

Los requerimientos para la generación de proxys para la carga diferida y el rastreo de cambios son distintos. Puedes referirte al artículo [**Requisitos para crear objetos proxy POCO**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx) para conocer los requisitos en cada caso.

### Importancia del tipo de la propiedad de navegación

Luego de tanta introducción, vamos a la pregunta principal, las propiedades de navegación conteniendo varias entidades (como listas, colecciones, enumeraciones, etc.), ¿cuál es la mejor manera de definirlas?

Primero pregúntate:

- ¿Vas a utilizar la carga diferida?
- ¿Vas a utilizar el rastreo de cambios?

Si la respuesta es sí para cualquiera o ambas, revisa los [**Requisitos para crear objetos proxy POCO**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx). Te darás cuenta que la única definición que permite ambas cosas es del tipo `public virtual ICollection<Property> Properties { get; set; }`.

Si la respuesta es no para ambos casos, define las propiedades de navegación como gustes, siempre y cuando te permita realizar lo que necesites. Como ejemplos:

- Si tienes una propiedad de navegación definida como `public virtual IEnumerable<Property> Properties { get; set; }` (una enumeración), no podrás agregar o eliminar elementos.
- Si la defines como `public virtual ICollection<Property> Properties { get; set; }` (una colección), no podrás realizar operaciones basadas en índices (como en las matrices unidimensionales, mal llamadas *arreglos*).
- Si la defines como `public virtual IList<Property> Properties { get; set; }` (una lista), podrás realizar de todo.

Recuerda que existen diferentes tipos de enumeraciones, colecciones y listas. En el caso de las colecciones, por ejemplo, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
ICollection<int> collection = new LinkedList<int>();
```

La colección recién creada está respaldada por el tipo `LinkedList<>`, la cual permite valores duplicados (podrás agregar dos veces el número `2`, y la colección tendrá dos elementos). Ahora, que tal si utilizas una colección diferente:

```
ICollection<int> collection = new HashSet<int>();
```

Ahora la colección está respaldada por el tipo `HashSet<>`, la cual no permite valores duplicados (al agregar más de una vez el número `2`, se descartarán todas las nuevas adiciones y la colección tendrá sólo un elemento).

Si no te agrada definir la propiedad de navegación como una interfaz (`IEnumerable<>`, `ICollection<>`, `IList<>`), puedes definirla como el tipo concreto (por ejemplo, `public virtual HashSet<Property> Properties { get; set; }`). Siempre y cuando no utilices la carga diferida ni el rastreo de cambios, esto no debería causarte problemas.

Comment: Muy completa tu respuesta!, mi pregunta ahora es, Que recomiendas o cual es la mejor practica posible para aplicaciones empresariales?

Comment: @KmiiloBerrioMontoya Eso es algo difícil de responder, ya que hay una serie de situaciones donde lo mejor es el resultado de una serie de circunstancias. Yo te podría recomendar usar Entity Framework 7 para estar listo para entornos basados en Mono, pero, ¿y si la empresa no puede hacer esto por limitaciones del hardware/software que utilizan? Si puedes ser lo más específico posible en las recomendaciones que buscas, puedo intentar lo mejor, pero recuerda que será mayoritariamente una opinión y no una respuesta irrefutable (:

Answer (score 0):

Al usar interfaces tienes la ventaja de utilizar la abstracción que éstas proveen, dicho de otra manera, si en una propiedad haces uso por ejemplo de List solamente puede aceptar variables de tipo List, mientras que si utilizas IList la propiedad puede recibir cualquier clase que implemente la interfaz IList, veamos un ejemplo:

```
public class ListadoTextos : IList<string> { /* código omitido */ }

public class Cliente
{
    public ListadoCadenas Intereses { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Gustos { get; set;  } // implementa interfaz IList<>
}


// uso de las clases anteriores
static void main()
{
    // creamos un objeto Cliente
    var c = new Cliente();
    //
    //ERROR: Intereses SÓLO permite objetos de tipo ListadoCadenas
    c.Intereses = new List<string>();
    //
    // PERFECTO: Gustos acepta CUALQUIER objeto que implement IList<string>
    c.Gustos = new List<string>();
    c.Gustos = new ListadoCadenas();
}
```

Comment: No logre comprender muy bien, para que utilizaríamos IList ? y no List, que diferencia tiene y en que caso se ve reflejado el uso de estas

Comment: @KmiiloBerrioMontoya ahí está expresado en el texto que te escribí, e igualmente si te dedicas a entender y probar el ejemplo que te proporcioné podrás comprender las diferencias.